# lintr fails to load in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, lintr

I am unable to get lintr to work in RStudio. Any suggestion appreciated. I believe I have updated everything. (For context, I am a newbie. I could certainly be doing something dumb.) Here's what happens to me:

```
> library(lintr)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lintr’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'processx', details:
  call: loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]])
  error: object 'vI' not found
```

Comment: Please verify that displayed input and output is correct; I reformatted it as code.

Comment: what version of R are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the reformatting. It is correct.

Comment: I am using R version 3.6.3

Answer (score 0):

I find that if I delete the folder holding all the packages and then reinstall and delete and reinstall R, the problems go away. This suggests that the problem has something to do with corrupt files. Note that removing the packages from within R and reinstalling is not sufficient.